# Replacing middle row of Matrix KDB

Tags: kdb

Matrix:

```
q)m:((1;2;3); (4;5;6); (7;8;9))
q)m
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Saving middle column as a

```
q)a:m[;1]
q)a
2 5 8
```

Replacing middle row of m with a:

```
q)m:.[m;(1;::);:;a]
q)m
1 2 3
2 5 8
7 8 9
```

Can anyone explain why `m:.[m;(1;::);:;a]` replaces the  middle row of m with a?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as an elided index, as detailed somewhat on this page: https://code.kx.com/q4m3/1_Q_Shock_and_Awe/

So

```
q)m[1;]
4 5 6
```

is the same as

```
q)m . (1;::)
4 5 6
```

and

```
q).[m;(1;::)]
4 5 6
```

This combines with the dyadic amend (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/) to achieve the result.

Note that it could have been achieved more easily with:

```
q)@[m;1;:;a]
1 2 3
2 5 8
7 8 9
```

so the dyadic amend was unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

`m` is made up of three vectors, `1 2 3`, `4 5 6`, `7 8 9`. When you have attempted to perform a replacement, you have specified to [index at depth](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#index-at) with `(1;::)`. This is telling q to go to the object at index 1 and select all of the items.

```
@[m;1]
```

The replacement you have performed is the same as

```
q)@[m;1;:;a]
1 2 3
2 5 8
7 8 9
```

If you wanted to perform a replacement on a column you would use the following index `(::;1)`. This says that for all of the objects, index to the first item.

For matrices this type of indexing results in the selection of columns.